# How to Disable the Gutenberg in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How to disable Gutenberg edit without any plugin and enable Classic Editor (Default)

[Screenshot of Gutenberg Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/809bh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also disable the Gutenberg Editor with code. Simply add the following to your functions.php file.

`add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10);`